# Merge result of two sql queries in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Query 1:

```
SELECT COUNT (A.EMPNO) AS [PRESENT]    
FROM ERPDATA.NIITESS.DBO.ZEMP_MASXST_WEB_AL A INNER                    
JOIN PPA_EVENTWISEEMPLOYEEMASTER B ON 
(CASE B.VC_BA WHEN '%' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(A.PDIBUSHORT)) ELSE B.VC_BA END) =  LTRIM(RTRIM(A.PDIBUSHORT))                   
AND (CASE B.VC_PA WHEN '%' THEN A.PA ELSE B.VC_PA END) = A.PA                
WHERE A.STATUS = 3  
AND A.EMPNO IN (SELECT VC_EMPCODE FROM ERPDATA.NIITESS.DBO.ADA_MXEASTER WHERE IN_ATTENDANCE_STATUS = 1 AND CH_ACTIVE = 'Y' AND VC_EMPCODE <> '')                    
GROUP BY B.IN_EVENTID
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT COUNT (A.EMPNO) AS [TOTAL]    
FROM ERPDATA.NIITESS.DBO.ZEMP_MASXST_WEB_AL A INNER                    
JOIN PPA_EVENTWISEEMPLOYEEMASTER B ON 
(CASE B.VC_BA WHEN '%' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(A.PDIBUSHORT)) ELSE B.VC_BA END) =  LTRIM(RTRIM(A.PDIBUSHORT))                   
AND (CASE B.VC_PA WHEN '%' THEN A.PA ELSE B.VC_PA END) = A.PA                
WHERE A.STATUS = 3
```

I want to merge the two results into two columns with an absent column = query 2 - query 1 to process speed faster. How can i do it?
EXAMPLE : 
I HAVE TWO RESULT :
//----------------------------------------QUERY : 1
1
2
3
4
//--------------------------------------
QUERY : 2
4
5
6
8
//------------------------------------OUTCOME AS in two columns
1   5
2   6
3   7
4   8

Comment: What will be the matching condition for your result. Your outcome can also be i.e. `(1,8), (2,5), (3, 6), (4,7)` or any other combination. There is no condition based on which querys will be joined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select a.C1-b.C2 as Res
 from
(
Select Count(*) as C1 from Users
Group by Name
) a
join
(
Select Count(*) as C2 from User2
Group by Name
) b ON 1=1 -- or desired condition if existing
```