# Combining the results from two separate queries in to two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am  working with two sql queries that I would like to combine as one so the result of the first query would be in the first column and the result of the second one in column two.  How can I acheive this?

I tried union, but it will put the results in two rows.. thats not what I want...

```
select count(*) as ColumnA from Inventory i, Sale s where i.vin=s.vin and i.condition='new' 

select count(*) as ColumnB from Inventory i, Sale s where i.vin=s.vin and i.condition='used' order by 1 desc;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge result of two sql queries in two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578983/merge-result-of-two-sql-queries-in-two-columns)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use combine two sub-queries in one query like this:

```
select
(select count(*) from Inventory i, Sale s where i.vin=s.vin and i.condition='new') as New,
(select count(*) from Inventory i, Sale s where i.vin=s.vin and i.condition='used') as Used
```

What were you trying to achieve with order by statement?

Answer (score 8):

You can obtain both counts at the same time with a little bit different query, which will be slightly more efficient than combining two queries:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.condition = 'new' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN i.condition = 'used' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
    Inventory i
JOIN
    Sale s ON i.vin = s.vin
```

Comment: Please don't use implicit joins, they have been deprecated for ages.

Comment: @Mureinik: I agree, it was copied from the question. I've changed it now though.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way would be to:

```
select
    (select count(*) as ColumnA from Inventory i, Sale s where i.vin=s.vin and i.condition='new') as newCount,
    (select count(*) as ColumnB from Inventory i, Sale s where i.vin=s.vin and  i.condition='used') as usedCount
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use another `SELECT` to combine results:

```
SELECT 
    (select count(*) from Inventory i, Sale s where i.vin=s.vin and i.condition='new') as ColumnA,
    (select count(*) from Inventory i, Sale s where i.vin=s.vin and i.condition='used') as ColumnB
```